# How should I calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n-3}{3n+4}\right)^{n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I have been studying for my Analysis exam but I have problem that can't solve.

Original:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2n-3}{3n+4}\right)^{n+1}$$

What I did trying to solve it making it looks like a sequence to e:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{3n+4}{3n+4}+\frac{-n-7}{3n+4}\right)^{n+1}$$
That made into:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{-n-7}{3n+4}\right)^{n+1}$$

I don't know what to do with -n to dissappear from the equation.

And this is what I should get in the end

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^{n} = e^a$$

I hope it is detailed enough.

Comment: What was the last step before you got stuck?

Comment: I don't know what to do with -n. All other steps are clear. This picture made after I made some changes.

Comment: BTW, in that link that you have provided (and please refrain from doing so next time, just add it directly to your question) - there's absolutely no sequence, and no problem to solve. Just an expression.

Comment: What do you mean "all other steps"? There are no steps listed there either!

Comment: It's a sequence converging to e and I have to calculate limn->infinite and that expression.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  To learn how to type pretty math, please see [the MathJax Guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which allows you to write interesting things.  $$\overbrace{\left(\ddot{\stackrel{\quad>}{\smile}}\right)}_{\begin{align}\hline\qquad\end{align}}$$Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't tend to $e$

Comment: There's no sequence there, only an expression. If you meant to ask about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ of that expression, then please be advised that it is not shown in that linked image. And again - none of the steps that you have made in order to solve it are listed there either.

Comment: This sequence goes to zero.

Comment: This question has been changed by OP. Orginally, it was about calculating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \biggr(\dfrac{-n-3}{3n+4}\biggr)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question has been changed by OP. Orginally, it was about calculating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \biggr(\dfrac{-n-3}{3n+4}\biggr)^{n+1}$.]

---

Your attempt is in the wrong track. The strategy should be very different from considering 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
because they are two different types of problems. In your case
$$
\frac{2n-3}{3n+4}\to\frac{2}{3}<1\quad \textrm{as } n\to\infty,
$$
 but in (1),
$$
1+\frac{1}{n}\to 1 \quad \textrm{as } n\to\infty
$$
In the later case, you have the form $1^\infty$ while in your question, you don't.

---

Note that
$$
\left(\frac{2n-3}{3n+4}\right)^{n+1}=\exp\left((n+1)\cdot\log\biggr(\frac{2n-3}{3n+4}\biggr)\right).
$$
What can you say about
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\log\biggr(\frac{2n-3}{3n+4}\biggr)?
$$

Note in particular that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\biggr(\frac{2n-3}{3n+4}\biggr)=\log\biggr(\frac23\biggr)<0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe:

$$\frac{n+3}{3n+4}=\frac13\,\frac{n+3}{n+\frac43}=\frac13\left(1+\frac{\frac53}{n+\frac43}\right)=\frac13+\frac5{9n+12}$$

and thus

$$1-\frac{n+3}{3n+4}=\frac23-\frac5{9n+12}=\frac23\left(1-\frac5{6n+8}\right)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It's also not the same, has no exponent.

Comment: @Rinner This is a *hint* and because of that the "can you take it from here?" Complete it and you'll see the limit is zero...

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{-n-3}{3n+4}=-\frac 13.$$

So

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left( 1+\frac{-n-3}{3n+4}\right)=\frac 23.$$

Now you know because

$$0<\frac 23<1$$

that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(\frac 23\right)^n=0.$$

So the limit you are looking for is $0$.

Comment: That is not the case: It's not that simple: it is exponential.

Comment: Add parenthesis in second limit.

Comment: @Rinner You should really think a little more deeper before you write a comment. This answer, just as mine, requires from you thing, justify and complete.

Comment: @Rinner I agree with DonAntonio.

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that you are not convinced of the fact that your limit is evidently 0, perhaps this alternative (longer) way can show you why.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2n-3}{3n+4}\right)^{n+1}=
$$
consider:
$$
\frac{2n-3}{3n+4}=\frac{2n-3-\alpha(3n+4)+\alpha(3n+4)}{3n+4}=\frac{2n-3-\alpha(3n+4)}{3n+4}+\alpha
$$
if $\alpha$ is chosen to be $\alpha\to\frac{2}{3}$ then by some elementary algebra:
$$
\frac{2n-3}{3n+4}=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{17}{9n+12}=\frac{2}{3}\left(1-\frac{17}{6n+8}\right)
$$
which means that your limit now is:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{17}{6n+8}\right)^{n+1}$$
now by a simple substitution $n\to \frac{1}{6} (17 t-8)$ you get:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}*\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)^{\frac{1}{6} (17 t-2)}=e^{-17/6}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}=0$$